# How to disable Special Keys using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw several jQuery/Js libraries about shortcut key of the keyboard, but i am still looking for the script which can override these special shortcut keys.

**mac** : <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

**windows** : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

is it possible?

Comment: http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/ might be a good place to start.

Comment: it is also not working for the above combinations.